# Kotlinのsingletonを初期化する方法

Tags: kotlin

お世話になっております。

さて、Kotlinを最近始めました。Kotlinではsingletonは言語レベルでサポートされていて、objectを使うとあります。しかし、objectではコンストラクタが使えません。

Javaの場合

```
class HBaseManager {
    private static HBaseManager ourInstance = new HBaseManager();
    private Configuration config =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
    private ArrayList<String> tableList = new ArrayList<>();

    static HBaseManager getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private HBaseManager() {
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","example.com:60000");
        listTables();
    }
}
```

のように書くと（この場合はHBaseの）初期化を済ませて、安全にアクセスできます。

あれこれKotlinのガイドを探してみましたが、singletonの初期化に関するものを見つけることができませんでした。

とりあえず、initialize()というメソッドを定義して、singletonを使う前にかならず呼ぶというルールにして当面は乗り切ろうと思いますが、何かしらの仕組みがあるはずだと思い、質問させていただきます。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

初期化ブロック (`init`) を利用するのはどうでしょうか

サンプル：

```
object Singleton {
    val message: String
    // ここで初期化を行う
    init {
        message = "Hello, world!"
        println("init complete")
    }
    fun hello() {
        println(message)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Singleton.hello()
    Singleton.hello()
}
```

出力結果：

```
init complete
Hello, world!
Hello, world!
```